# FMDB sqlite's sql query not working

Tags: ios, iphone, sql, sqlite, fmdb

I am creating a temp table using the following SQL query. But its not showing any results (result set is empty) when I execute it programmatically, and shows records when I execute it manually on the database.

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create temp table search2 as select  Observationsid from Observations where admin_id=%d AND teacher_id=%d AND observation_type=%d AND isvalid='yes' AND date BETWEEN '12-20-2013' AND '12-23-2013'",appDelegate.admin_id,appDelegate.teacher_id,appDelegate.observationType];
FMResultSet *results=[appDelegate.database executeQuery:query];
```

Nslogged query:
Printing description of results->_query:

```
create temp table search2 as select Observationsid from Observations where admin_id=2 AND teacher_id=1 AND observation_type=2 AND isvalid='yes' AND date BETWEEN '12-20-2013' AND '12-23-2013'
```

and records are there in database.

Comment: Unrelated, but I notice that you're using `MM-DD-YYYY` format for your dates. You really want to use `YYYY-MM-DD` or, better, rely upon `FMDatabase` to convert your `NSDate` values for you. But if you use what you have, a text string of `12-21-2052` is `BETWEEN '12-20-2013' AND '12-23-2013'`, which is probably not what you intended. Remember, SQLite does not have proper date formats, so choose an appropriate format (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD` format) or let `FMDatabase` handle this for you, using `NSDate` objects.

Comment: @Rob Hey thank you very much. I am having confusion related to date format for sqlite and nsdate to database date format but i didn't take efforts to ask question. Will u plzz give me proper example or link of tutorial which will explain a little bit more about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added some example date logic to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL statement shouldn't return results, so you should use `executeUpdate` method rather than a `executeQuery` method. You should not see any results from this. If you want to see the results, do a separate `executeQuery` statement returning the results from `search2`. (I assume you're building the `search2` table for a reason.)

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create temp table search2 as select  Observationsid from Observations where admin_id=%d AND teacher_id=%d AND observation_type=%d AND isvalid='yes' AND date BETWEEN '12-20-2013' AND '12-23-2013'",appDelegate.admin_id,appDelegate.teacher_id,appDelegate.observationType];
if (![appDelegate.database executeUpdate:query])
    NSLog(@"create error: %@", [appDelegate.database lastErrorMessage]);

query = @"SELECT * FROM search2";
FMResultSet *results = [appDelegate.database executeQuery:query];
if (!results)
    NSLog(@"create error: %@", [appDelegate.database lastErrorMessage]);
```

---

By the way, while you can get away with `stringWithFormat` for this particular SQL, that's not a good idea. You generally want to use the `?` placeholders, e.g.

```
NSString *query = @"create temp table search2 as select  Observationsid from Observations where admin_id=? AND teacher_id=? AND observation_type=? AND isvalid='yes' AND date BETWEEN '12-20-2013' AND '12-23-2013'";
if (![appDelegate.database executeUpdate:query, @(appDelegate.admin_id), @(appDelegate.teacher_id), @(appDelegate.observationType)])
    NSLog(@"create error: %@", [appDelegate.database lastErrorMessage]);
```

---

Unrelated, but I notice that you're using `MM-DD-YYYY` format text string for your dates. That's not going to work. SQLite doesn't natively "understand" dates. Notably, if you've stored your dates in `MM-DD-YYYY` format, a text string of `12-21-2052` is `BETWEEN '12-20-2013' AND '12-23-2013'` (because text strings are compared in alphabetically order), which is probably not what you intended. See [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

But, fortunately, FMDB does the `NSDate` conversion for you, storing it as numeric value. So, for example, let's assume your table was defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Observations
    (Observationsid   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
     admin_id         INTEGER, 
     teacher_id       INTEGER,
     observation_type INTEGER,
     isvalid          TEXT,
     date             REAL);
```

You really want to use `YYYY-MM-DD` or, better, rely upon `FMDatabase` to convert your `NSDate` values for you.  Remember, SQLite does not have proper date formats, so choose an appropriate format (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD` format) or let `FMDatabase` handle this for you, using `NSDate` objects.

If you want to facilitate the conversion of date strings to dates, you can use a `NSDateFormatter`, e.g.:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yyyy";

NSDate *someDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"12-22-2013"];
if (![appDelegate.database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO Observations (admin_id, teacher_id, observation_type, isvalid, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", @(appDelegate.admin_id), @(appDelegate.teacher_id), @(appDelegate.observationType), @"yes", someDate])
    NSLog(@"insert error: %@", [appDelegate.database lastErrorMessage]);
```

Or, if I wanted to select the dates between these two dates:

```
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"12-20-2013"];
NSDate *endDate   = [formatter dateFromString:@"12-23-2013"];

NSString *query = @"create temp table search2 as select  Observationsid, date from Observations where admin_id=? AND teacher_id=? AND observation_type=? AND isvalid='yes' AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
if (![appDelegate.database executeUpdate:query, @(appDelegate.admin_id), @(appDelegate.teacher_id), @(appDelegate.observationType), startDate, endDate])
    NSLog(@"create error: %@", [appDelegate.database lastErrorMessage]);

query = @"SELECT * FROM search2";
FMResultSet *results = [appDelegate.database executeQuery:query];
if (!results)
    NSLog(@"select error: %@", [appDelegate.database lastErrorMessage]);
while ([results next])
    NSLog(@"%d %@", [results intForColumnIndex:0], [results dateForColumnIndex:1]);
```

If you want to avoid this `NSDate` logic, you could alternatively consciously store dates in a text format in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. That works, too. Again, see that [Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) page for a list of valid text formats for dates.

Comment: Thank u very much. :) . I was also trying                        FMResultSet *results=[appDelegate.database executeUpdate:query];        but i was using FMResultSet, therefore it was giving error.

Comment: yes, a problem was that i was not knowing, sqlite stores date in numeric format and it is handled automatically by FMDatabase.